# does there always exist a vector v such that, the partial derivative of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ in the direction of v is zero?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Does there always exist a vector v such that, the partial derivative of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ in the direction of v is zero?
My approach would be saying that the directional derivative of f equals:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}.... $

and then we consider it in the direction v with:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} v_x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} v_y + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} v_z = 0$$

and since the derivative is a constant just solve for $v_x, v_y, v_z,...,v_n$ and call it proven, stating that there always exist a direction v in which the slope would be zero.
Is this approach rigorous/correct?

Comment: What happens if $n=1$? otherwise, your approach seems fine

Comment: Are you asking if this is true for all functions $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$, or asking whether your method will work given a specific function?

Comment: There is a problem here: If $\partial_xf, \partial_yf, \partial_zf$ are linearly independent the only solution to your equation would be $v=0$ and the only "direction" in which the directional derivative vanishes would be the "direction" zero. So it will only be possible to find such a direction if the partial derivatives of $f$ at the given point are linearly dependent.

Comment: @Lukas Here $\partial_x f, \partial_y f, \partial_z f$ are all scalars, so as long as there are at least two of them, they are linearly dependent. Hence my comment about the $n=1$ case.

Comment: For some intuition behind this problem, notice that $x_0$ belongs to the level set $f^{-1}(f(x_0))$ for any $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$. If you pick a direction vector $v$ that's tangent to $f^{-1}(f(x_0))$ at $x=x_0$ you'll get that the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $v$ is $0$. Do you see why?

Comment: I don't agree that the directional derivative of f equals $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}....$.

Answer (score 4):

The directional derivative in the direction of a unit vector $\vec u$ can be calculated most easily by taking the dot product of the gradient vector $\nabla f$ with $\vec u$:
$$D_{\vec u}f = \nabla f \cdot \vec u$$
If $\nabla f \ne \vec 0$ at a particular point, then at that point any vector $\vec u$ perpendicular to $\nabla f$ will be a direction in which the directional derivative is zero.  In general, if we are in $\mathbb R^n$ (with $n \ge 2$), this will be an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace.  On the other hand, if $\nabla f = \vec 0$ at a particular point, then at that point the directional derivative is zero in *every* direction.